# Is it possible to trigger a pop-up on foucs event in input element Semantic-UI-Vue

Tags: vue.js, semantic-ui

I tried using a popup inside a button. What I want to achieve is to activate the popup whenever the button element is hovered what I've tried so far is this:

`<sui-popup open content="Hello. This is an inverted popup" > <sui-button inline flowing hoverable slot="trigger" @hover="activatePopup()">Show flowing popup</sui-button> </sui-popup>`

I am using Vue.js 2.6.11

Answer (score 2):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3327) should awnser your question.